# ubuntu virtual env not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

This is a simple question but I can't figure out what's the problem.
I have created virtual enviroment (in my home folder) by:

```
$ python -m venv ll_env
```

Then I have tried to activate it:

```
$ source ll_env/bin/activate
```

and I get the message:

```
bash: ll_env/bin/activate: No such file or directory
```

However, the files are clearly there.

```
name@name:~/ll_env$ ls
bin  include  lib

name@aname:~/ll_env$ cd bin
name@name:~/ll_env/bin$ ls
python  python3  python3.6
```

What might be the problem? I have Anaconda from Continium analytics installed. Can this cause the problem? Thanks.

Comment: According to the output of the last `ls` command in the question, there's no `ll_env/bin/activate`.

Comment: but I've searched for how to activate virtual env and this seems like the way todo

Comment: Did you got warnings ? Like `The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not available.` ? Can you confirme you are using python3? if yes, you could try `apt-get install python3-venv`, remove the directory and try again

Comment: No, I got no warning at all. Everything seems to be running fine.